# django class based generic view "CreateView" unique slug error handeling

Tags: python, django

So I have a CreateView and it works 99% the way I want. If a user enters a letter in an integer field it tells the user to enter a number, if a user leaves a required field blank it tells them that they need to fill it in. This is all great, CreateView handles the errors for me. However, for obvious reasons, I am not letting the user create the slug field, this is created automatically by taking the date and two other fields combining them and slugifying them. If the user attempts to create a record that wouldn't result in a unique slug then the form is invalid but CreateView doesn't give any constructive feedback (unless you are in debug mode, then you get UNIQUE constraint failed).

If I add the code below to my CreateView, then I need to re-define all the error responses that CreateView was handling so nicely before.

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    return HttpResponse(#define stuff here)
```

Is there a way I can have CreateView handle invalid forms normally (as if I didn't have `def form_invalid(self, form):`) except for when there is a slug conflict?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by calling the parent's class version of `form_invalid` inside your overriding of `form_invalid`.

Example:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        if my_condition:  # Check whatever you want
            return HttpResponse('reason it failed')
        else:  # Or call the parent class version
            return super(MyCreateView, self).form_invalid(form)
```